# Debugging principles/core topics in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, debugging, testing

I am interested in devoting a good amount of time to improving my debugging ability and am looking for a list of core topics that I need to cover in order to be versed in the principles of commonly used and advanced debugging/testing techniques.

Initially, I figured I would just read through the gdb documentation and glean debugging techniques from its functionality; however, other than jumping into it to get the line number of a segfault and maybe running `bt`, months later I am still resorting to mass `printf`'s as my default strategy. I feel this is because I don't have any well defined strategies that I could effect through more sophisticated means.

Although my question is in relation to C/C++, and although I operate within a UNIX environment, I would be willing to look at generalized material, or even topics covered in other languages if they will improve my understanding of key concepts.

Comment: I agree with H2CO3, they'll give you an idea of program flow. But I'm curious to any answers to this question too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325853/what-are-your-favorite-debugging-techniques-in-c

Comment: @pauluss86 I disagree, if you don't already know the programs flow then you shouldn't try to modify it. First you understand and then and only then you should take action. I prefer the good ol' breakpoint -> stepdown -> while watching locals method.

Comment: @Christian: you're right there, but I meant using it as support to check whether the intended program flow is indeed being executed, not changing it. Afaic adding print statements doesn't change the flow. Also I'm interchanging `print` with `log` here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have multiple direct strategies which you should consider:

- Mass printfs cry for a **logging** solution. You have many options here, but logging extensively isn't particularly a bad strategy, it is in fact vital for any form of client-side debugging.
- Extensively use **assertions** (and never disable them, even in "release" code). Always write checks for all potential errors and fail as soon as possible (use exceptions in C++ -- always throw, never catch).
- Learning to **master gdb** within emacs is useful. Learning how to step the program, how to set up breakpoints and how to inspect local variables is usually more than enough.
- **Unit testing** is something to consider too. Especially since small tests are easier to debug, because they are not surrounded by the noise of a fully featured program. Write tests before the code, or better, have someone else write the tests.

More generally, the following points, although not directly related to debugging, will benefit you:

- **Learning** how a program is executed (learn eg. about stack frames and a small intro to assembly) may prove useful in certain situations where a bug is corrupting memory. More generally, never stop learning stuff about your environment.
- In C++, use **good practices**: RAII, the standard library, failing as soon as possible, etc. This has a strong tendency to reduce debugging effort, esp. since debuggers can pretty print stuff from the standard library. Also, coding a simply as possible has a positive effect on debugging time.
- Use (distributed) **version control**. Always. You'll see the benefits once you'll get accustomed to it (eg. in combination with unit tests, you have the almighty [`git bisect`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) available to you).

Comment: Do people actually use `git bisect`?

Comment: @arxanas: In projects with a lot of people/commits, yes (I mean outside linux kernel bug finding). This can even be automated to some extent.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to become a more advanced C/C++ debugger, learn some assembly (you don't need to be an expert, just some basic knowledge is good), learn about machine registers, and learn about your platform's ABI (application binary interface, specifically how function arguments and the stack work) so that you don't have to rely on `printf`'s everywhere to see what your program is doing.  It would also be a good idea to learn how to examine memory, and know what you're looking for at memory addresses, which once you get decent at assembly and understand how machine instructions interact with the register set, you'll quickly know where to look to find a pointer address or memory location to set as a watch-point or to look up as a block and see what's going on with your data-structures in a given memory location.

For instance, debugging recursive algorithms can be difficult if something is occuring a couple levels down ... depending on how many levels, you could end up outputting reams of data that will take forever to sift through, or you could find yourself stopping on a break-point forever.  If you understand how the stack works with a recursive algorithm though, you can set conditional break points that watch the stack pointer registers, as well as other memory addresses on the stack to properly stop your program at the point where the errors in the recursive algorithm occur, rather than having to sift through meaningless data.  So you run your program until it stops, inspect the back-trace, look at some of the variables on the stack as well as the stack-pointer register, and then set a conditional break-point that will stop you at the proper recursive point in the algorithm.

BTW, as a quick note, don't use `printf` ... it's buffered on `stdout`, which means by the time you see the error on output, your bug may have already propagated to something else such as a weird memory corruption error, etc.  Even if you flush the buffer for `stdout` by placing an end-line character, etc., you're still going to end up muxing error messages with the normal output of the program. Instead of `printf` use `fprintf`, and output to `stderr`.  That won't be buffered, it will print to the output immediately, and should you desire to save the your program's output, the error messages won't be muxed with the output of the program.

Answer (score 3):

I want to cover the technique of using assertions a little more.

Assertions let you specify what you expect to be true at any point in the code.  At the beginning of a function, you can use assertions to make sure that the parameters had reasonable values.  These are called preconditions.  And the end of the function, you can check to make sure that what you are about to return is consistent with the purpose of the function.  These are called post-conditions.  In the middle of the function you can make sure any intermediate calculations are reasonable (although you should generally try to make your functions small enough that there aren't a lot of intermediate calculations).

With classes, you can check to make sure good values are passed into the constructor.  In other methods, you can make sure that the general state of the class is reasonable before the method returns.  These are called invariants.

When I'm debugging, I usually find that bugs are hard to find because I missed some assertions, letting the crash get farther away from the source of the problem.  I use the debugging process to help fix that.  I start with where the crash actually occurred, and think "at this level of abstraction, what was wrong?".  If it crashed in the middle of the function, I might realize that the parameters passed to the function weren't right, so I add additional assertions near the beginning of the function to catch those.  When I run it the next time and it crashes, the crash happens a little sooner.  If the crash now happens at the top of the function, I go up one level of the stack and ask "why didn't the caller pass the right value?".  I might then realize that some intermediate calculation was wrong, so I add an assertion there to catch it earlier.  The intermediate calculation may have been due to another function returning the wrong value, in which case I'll add a post-condition assertion to catch that earlier.  It may have been due to the current function not having been passed the right parameters, so I add a pre-condition assertion to this function.

Each time I add an assertion, I make the crash happen closer to the real source of the problem.  Eventually I get to a point where the crash happens at the real logic error, and the fix is obvious.  But by going through this process, I've also made it more likely that future problems will be easier to find.

You can apply similar reasoning when doing unit testing.  Ask "what was wrong with my tests that made this problem not be caught earlier?"

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with resorting to `printf`. Infact, it has many advantages:

- A `printf` statement which has been commented out is a clear indicator of *past* debugging attempts which indicates that there *might* be something fishy going on with that area of code.
- `printf` statements are **easy to understand** if they are verbose and well crafted. Even the beginners understand their meaning and how to use them.
- `printf` statements actually **force you to think about the problem** and what *causes* it. You have to try to follow the logical control flow and data flow to *understand the problem*. This then enforces your understanding of the *whole* system.

Infact, I think that people who are taught to rely on tools to debug their code have a tendency to consult their tools first before actually even *trying* to figure out the reason for the ill-behaviour in their code! Of course, in many cases debuggers are preferred but it's clear that person who **thinks** first instead of blindly turning to the debugger is the person who inherently gains better understanding of the problem, better understanding of the faulty state of the program and ultimately **better understanding of the cause of the problem**.

[Let me quote **Rob Pike** here:](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1941206)

> "When something went wrong, I'd reflexively start to dig in to the problem, examining stack traces, sticking in print statements, invoking a debugger, and so on. But Ken would just stand and think, ignoring me and the code we'd just written. After a while I noticed a pattern: Ken would often understand the problem before I would, and would suddenly announce, "I know what's wrong." He was usually correct. I realized that Ken was building a mental model of the code and when something broke it was an error in the model. By thinking about *how* that problem could happen, he'd intuit where the model was wrong or where our code must not be satisfying the model.
>
> Ken taught me that thinking before debugging is extremely important. If you dive into the bug, you tend to fix the local issue in the code, but if you think about the bug first, how the bug came to be, you often find and correct a higher-level problem in the code that will improve the design and prevent further bugs."

Comment: Use `fprintf(stderr, ...)` over `printf`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read a book about "Test Driven Development" (TDD), e.g. the one by Kent Beck.

Answer (score 1):

Learn how to use Valgrind, at least it's default tool [Memcheck](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html). It will save you a lot of time when debugging various memory management issues such as:

- Overrunning and underrunning heap blocks
- Using undefined values
- Using already deallocated objects